# FragmentBasics gives Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using the code from Google's example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) in the zip file.

When I run it as it is everything goes well.

If I remove the support lib and change FragmentActivity to Activity and support.Fragment to Fragment ( also gertsupportFragmentManager() to FragmentManager() ) and the Manifest to point to api 17 like this :
    `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />`

I'm getting a `NPE` when I click the list Item. I don't understand what changed and can't find the R.id.article.

Since I haven't change the layout files and I didn't mess much  with the code I'm guessing it has something to do with the APIs and/or the lifecycle of the Activity/Fragments in place of FragmentActivity and support.Fragment .

error is :

```
11-07 18:30:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1266): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 18:30:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1266): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-07 18:30:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     at com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment.updateArticleView(ArticleFragment.java:63)
11-07 18:30:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     at com.example.android.fragments.MainActivity.onArticleSelected(MainActivity.java:70)
11-07 18:30:20.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     at com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment.onListItemClick(HeadlinesFragment.java:75)
```

ArticleFragment code is here :

```
public class ArticleFragment extends android.app.Fragment {
final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
int mCurrentPosition = -1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
    // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
    // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // During startup, check if there are arguments passed to the fragment.
    // onStart is a good place to do this because the layout has already been
    // applied to the fragment at this point so we can safely call the method
    // below that sets the article text.
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        // Set article based on argument passed in
        updateArticleView(args.getInt(ARG_POSITION));
    } else if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
        // Set article based on saved instance state defined during onCreateView
        updateArticleView(mCurrentPosition);
    }
}

public void updateArticleView(int position) {
    TextView article = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);
    article.setText(Ipsum.Articles[position]);
    mCurrentPosition = position;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Save the current article selection in case we need to recreate the fragment
    outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);
}
}
```

Ipsum class :

```
package com.example.android.fragments;

public class Ipsum {

static String[] Headlines = {
    "Article One",
    "Article Two"
};

static String[] Articles = {
    "Article One\n\nExcepteur pour-over occaecat squid biodiesel umami gastropub, nulla laborum salvia dreamcatcher fanny pack. Ullamco culpa retro ea, trust fund excepteur eiusmod direct trade banksy nisi lo-fi cray messenger bag. Nesciunt esse carles selvage put a bird on it gluten-free, wes anderson ut trust fund twee occupy viral. Laboris small batch scenester pork belly, leggings ut farm-to-table aliquip yr nostrud iphone viral next level. Craft beer dreamcatcher pinterest truffaut ethnic, authentic brunch. Esse single-origin coffee banksy do next level tempor. Velit synth dreamcatcher, magna shoreditch in american apparel messenger bag narwhal PBR ennui farm-to-table.",
    "Article Two\n\nVinyl williamsburg non velit, master cleanse four loko banh mi. Enim kogi keytar trust fund pop-up portland gentrify. Non ea typewriter dolore deserunt Austin. Ad magna ethical kogi mixtape next level. Aliqua pork belly thundercats, ut pop-up tattooed dreamcatcher kogi accusamus photo booth irony portland. Semiotics brunch ut locavore irure, enim etsy laborum stumptown carles gentrify post-ironic cray. Butcher 3 wolf moon blog synth, vegan carles odd future."
};
}
```

Comment: What is line 63 `ArticleFragment.java`?

Comment: article.setText(Ipsum.Articles[position]);  takes data from an Ipsum java class

Comment: I think in line 'article.setText(Ipsum.Articles[position]);', variable article is 'null' or problem could be with 'getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);' .Check R.id.article

Comment: just added the code of that class. I have print the position variable and its not null so how Ipsum.Articles[0] or Ipsum.Articles[1] is null ? Sorry I'm not so experienced hope it doesn't sounds naive

Comment: May be you can try to create/get instance of 'TextView' in onCreate method and then later you can use it in updateArticleView method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `TextView` as a class member

Initialize it in `onCreateView`

```
TextView article; 
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
    // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
    // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    }
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false); 
     article = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the mentioned in the current infalted layout. If not found you get NPE. So infalte the layout use the view object to initialize textview.

Comment: Yeap it works! Need 2' more to accept the answer. 
However I don't understand what happened and I need to declare the TextView in onCreateView() taking into account it was working before with the support lib. Thank you

Comment: @NewUserSO you need to initialize textview with the inflated view object. the text view is in the inflated layout. So use the view object to initialize views.

Answer (score 2):

The answer marked as accepted did not work for me.  I ended up finding a detailed answer here (http://marksunghunpark.blogspot.com/2015/04/googles-fragment-example-error.html)

From Sunghun's Blog:

> It will load news content when you click a item from the headlines.
>   The `MainActivity` switches Fragment to display it in a handset but it
>   displays news content in the second pane in a table device. Error
>   comes from `ArticleFragment` class. When the `MainActivity` loads two pane
>   `news_articles.xml` in `/res/layout-large`, it cannot find view having ID `'article'` because it tried to find the view by calling
>   `getActivity().findViewById()`. This does not work. You have to read the
>   `'article'` `TextView` from `rootView` of the `article_view.xml`.

Comment: Yup, I'm trying to learn Fragments on a modern platform (i.e. android.app.Fragment) and Mark's detailed fix worked for me as well.